# undefined offset of full array but vardump is full

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I have a few problems with my PHP code.

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST['IP_adress'])){
    $IP_adress = $_POST['IP_adress'];
    $block[4] = explode(".",$IP_adress);
    $i = 0;
    var_dump($block);
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
      if ($block[$i]<0 || $block[$i]>255){//here is line 9
        $_SESSION['IP_error'] = "non-valid IP adress";
        header('Location: controle.php');
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

when i launch the code, the var_dump function says that my array ($block) is  correctly filled but I have this errors.

```
array(1) { [4]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "255" [1]=> string(3) "255" [2]=> string(3) "255" [3]=> string(3) "255" } }

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/select.php on line 9

[output errors][1]
```

Can you help me please ?

p.s. sorry for bad grammar and english. French native speaker here !

Comment: shouldn't it be `$block = explode(".",$IP_adress);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **line #5**, you used `$block[4] = explode(".",$IP_adress);` and that is what the var_dump's output is telling you.

You have created an associated array with your exploded IP **array** stored as a value at key `4` of array `$block`. To access exploded IP fields you can either modify **line #5** to `$block = explode(".",$IP_adress);` or modify **line #9** to `if ($block[4][$i]<0 || $block[4][$i]>255){`.